# Sort 2d array (with inconsistent column names) by first column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

How can I sort an array or rows by the first value in each row?

```
$array = [
    ['item1' => 80],
    ['item2' => 25],
    ['item3' => 85],
];
```

Desired output:

```
[
    ['item2' => 25],
    ['item1' => 80],
    ['item3' => 85],
]
```

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426917/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-one-of-the-fields-of-the-inner-array-in

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), a function that sorts arrays via a user defined function. Something like:

```php
usort(
    $yourArray, 
    fn(array $a, array $b): int /* (1),(2) range: -1 ... 1 */
    => reset($a) /* get the first array elements from $a */ 
       <=>  /* (3) <--- the spaceship operator */
       reset($b) /* and from $b for comparison */
);
```

1. `fn (...) => ...` [Arrow Functions (PHP 7.4)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.arrow-functions)
2. `function name (): int` [Return type declarations (PHP 7.0)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)
3. `<=>` [Spaceship Operator (PHP 7.0)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op)

*([see it live on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/B2e2f))*

---

Expressed in older, well-aged PHP:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $a = reset($a); // get the first array elements
    $b = reset($b); // for comparison.
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($yourArray, "cmp")
```

*([see it live on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PPNKR))*

Compare this [with the answer of one of the questions duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426917/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-one-of-the-fields-of-the-inner-array-in/2426960#2426960).

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `usort`

```
$array = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'item1' => 80,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'item2' => 25,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'item3' => 85,
  ),
);

function my_sort_cmp($a, $b) {
    reset($a);
    reset($b);
    return current($a) < current($b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'my_sort_cmp');

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item2] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item1] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item3] => 85
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern PHP, call `usort()` with the syntactic sugary goodness of an arrow function and the spaceship operator.  Access the first element of each row with `current()` or `reset()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7Ytu6))

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => current($a) <=> current($b));
```

The equivalent with fewer total function calls: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eRX6l))

```
array_multisort(array_map('current', $array), $array);
```