# PHP multiple array sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort multiple array by one value in array. Unfortunately, I can not sort this inside the database. I can only get array like this.

My Array look like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10913
            [name] => NAME 1
            [logo_img] => 28361bd6114a32daafcf150da5ee1d33.jpeg
            [has_frame] => t
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10902
            [name] => Name 2
            [logo_img] => d0642d5efeabe8b861f2f32fa17f35b3.jpeg
            [has_frame] => t
            [weight] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8887
            [name] => Some name 3
            [logo_img] => 12e47533604438bf390d69218434b630.jpeg
            [has_frame] => f
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 49
            [name] => Some name 4
            [logo_img] => 5971148b049c5bb0b6e402a1de1836ef.jpeg
            [has_frame] => t
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10871
            [name] => name2
            [logo_img] => 7dcc1a6058a81b4e45de5f2274025907.jpeg
            [has_frame] => t
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1880
            [name] => name 4
            [logo_img] => dc05764ea71425a4a653b81997e7d929.jpeg
            [has_frame] => f
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9678
            [name] => name 33
            [logo_img] => 8ded98244a6928d5179398fa9d3b59bc.jpeg
            [has_frame] => t
            [weight] => 5
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2880
            [name] => name r
            [logo_img] => 09876329a5ac2a84e9f83923c75e780c.jpeg
            [has_frame] => f
            [weight] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8265
            [name] => name 5
            [logo_img] => 487ed3c676666e380f813f5f1a9fb040.jpeg
            [has_frame] => t
            [weight] => 1
        )

)
```

I need to order this array by weight element DESC. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. what have you tried so far?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: I try array_multisort(), but no effect.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426917/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-one-of-the-fields-of-the-inner-array-i) could help as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value  this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I did it:

```
usort($object, 'cmp');

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($b['weigth'], $a['weigth']); // or -> weigth
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

This lists a lot of information on sorting,

if you need to sort using the key, try

```
ksort($array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 //You can use `uasort` that has a comparison function that can be defined by user;


//if the name of the whole array is $array

//define a function 

 function compare($obj1,$obj2){
     if($obj1['weight']==$obj2['weight']){
         return 0;
     }
  return $obj1['weight']<$obj2['weight']?1:-1;

}
//the comparison operator in the function `compare` in the second return determines the order of the array elements.


 //Now call the function with your array

 uasort($array,'compare');
```